# How can I send Chainlink Bridge Outgoing Token info to the AWS API Gateway as x-api-key?

Tags: chainlink

Bridge Page (https://i.stack.imgur.com/nh0kS.png)

How can I send the "Outgoing Token" information shown in the Bridge page that I defined on the Chainlink node operator to the API Gateway URL address specified in the trigger of AWS Lambda as "x-api-key"?

AWS Trigger Definition (https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6EER.png)

Is the Headers definition made in the Job definition?

`fetch [type=bridge name="testbridge" requestData="{\\"id\\": $(jobSpec.externalJobID), \\"data\\": { \\"testId\\": $(decode_cbor. testId)}"]`

Postman Sample (https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKOHu.png)

I made the API key value of the API Gateway in the AWS Lambda trigger the same as the "Outgoing Token" value shown on the Bridge page. When I ran the job, I got an error at the step-fetch:

```
fetch bridge
got error from https://api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ExternalAdapter: (status code 403) {"message":"Forbidden"}

name: testbridge

requestData: {"id": $(jobSpec.externalJobID), "data": { "testId": $(decode_cbor.testId)}}
```

Comment: Did you add the Outgoing Token as a key in the API Gateway?